# Random determinant problem

Tags: probability

Suppose we have $X_i$ random matrices $i\in \{1,\dots,\ n\}$ with dimension $M\times N$ and i.i.d. entries. Then we form the function $f(a_1,\dots, a_n)=\mathbb E \det(I+\sum a_iX_iX_i^H)$ where $a_i$ are positive real constants. Can we claim $f$ is monotonic in each 
$a_i,\dots, a_n $? Here $^H$ is the Hermitian transpose (conjugate transpose).

Comment: aren't all eigen values monotone (and positive) by minimax ?  Remark: guessing on $^H$.

Comment: @mike Could you please elaborate on this? thanks

Comment: I'd be happy too, but what does $^H$ mean ?  No sense in running off if its not what I'm guessing.

Comment: @mike When $X$ is a complex valued matrix $X^H$ is the conjugate transpose http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose.

Answer (score 1):

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courant_minimax_principle

For a matrix of the form $A^TA, \langle A^TA v ,v \rangle  $ that appears in the minimax principle is $\| Av \|^2 \ge 0$.
Then I think it is easy to see that each eigenvalue of matrices of the form 
$I+\sum a_iX_iX_i^T$ is increasing as a function of $a_i$.  E.g., for the largest it is just the observation that $sup_{\| v \| = 1} \|v \|^2 + \sum a_i \| X_iv \|^2$ is increasing.  Then, since the minimax principle also shows  that all eigenvalues are non-negative. the determinant will be increasing as the product of positive increasing fctns, and the expectation, which is a linear combination of increasing functions with positive  coefficients is also.

Comment: Thank you. It will take some time for me to understand this, after studying the relevant theory. In that case, I will use this result in a paper. I would like to acknowledge your help if I submit the paper. Would you mind that?

Comment: Could you please explain what happens to the expectation? The Wiki article does not talk about random matrix.

Comment: the expected determinant is a linear combination with positive weights of determinants each of which  is increasing, this is literally true of the distribution of the random guys has finite support, and is true in the sense of being a limit of such guys, or an intergral of them, if you  prefer.

Comment: The wikipedia page defines Courant minimax priniciple only for real valued matrices. Isn't that a a problem here since in my question $X_i$ are complex valued?