# Is this determinant identity true?

Tags: matrices, determinant

I simulated the following $$\det(I+[A|B][A|B]^*)\geq\det(I+[B][B]^*)$$ and every time I get a true result. So how can I prove this statement? Here $[A|B]$ is matrix augmentation. $I$ is the identity matrix, $A,B$ are complex valued matrices and $^*$ is the conjugate transpose operation. In my first simulation I used randomly generated complex square matrices so I guess they all probably turned out to be invertible. Then I simulated with $A,B$ non square, still the identity holds.

I know that $[A|B][A|B]^*$ is positive semi-definite (PSD) and $I+[A|B][A|B]^*$ is PD so is $I+[B][B]^*$. So may be the answer lies in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Weyl's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality) says (in its special case) that if $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ Hermitian matrices, then $$\tag{Weyl}
\lambda_i(A)+\lambda_n(B)\leq\lambda_i(A+B)\leq\lambda_i(A)+\lambda_1(B), \quad i=1,\ldots,n.$$
Here $\lambda_i(\cdot)$ denotes the $i$th eigenvalue of its argument ordered in the descending order (so that $\lambda_1(\cdot)$ denotes the maximal and $\lambda_n(\cdot)$ the minimal eigenvalue of the argument).

It follows that if, in addition, $B$ is positive semi-definite (and hence $\lambda_n(B)\geq 0$) then we can drop $\lambda_n(B)$ in (Weyl) to get
$$
\lambda_i(A)\leq\lambda_i(A+B), \quad i=1,\ldots,n.
$$
Now since $A$ is positive semi-definite as well, we have
$$
\det(A+B)=\prod_{i=1}^n\lambda_i(A+B)\geq\prod_{i=1}^n\lambda_i(A)=\det(A).
$$

The statement in the question is just the consequence of this fact (with $A$ replaced by $I+AA^*$ and $B$ replaced by $BB^*$).

Comment: Thank you very much. I will use this in my research. Do you mind if I acknowledge you in my paper?

Comment: If you like :) I think this might be found in some matrix analysis book anyway, although it's really just a simple consequence of the Weyl's inequality so that maybe it's just not stated as a separate theorem normally.

Comment: I was wondering if I can use this Weyl's inequality to solve the follow proxlem. Looks like we can. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/648738/random-determinant-problem. Do you think so? $\det(I+aA+bB)\leq\det(I+aA+cA+bB)$ for $a,b,c>0$ and $A,B,C$ positive semi-definite.

Comment: It looks like it's the same problem.

Comment: Is this proof true even for $\det(A-B)>\det(A)$? Because we can put the minus inside

Comment: In that case you have $\lambda_i(A)-\lambda_n(B)\leq\lambda_i(A-B)$, which does not imply at all that $\lambda_i(A)\leq\lambda_i(A-B)$.