# Matrix determinant problem: Solution Verification

Tags: probability, determinant, solution-verification

I previously posted [Random determinant problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/648738/random-determinant-problem) but did not understand the answer. Recently I came accross a solution method and would like to verify it here.

**Question:** Is $$\mathbb E\det(I+a_1A_1+\dots + a_nA_n)$$ monotonic in $(a_1,\dots,\ a_n)$? Here $a_i$s are positive reals and $A_i$s are random positive semi-definite matrices. That is $A_i=X_iX_i^*$ where $X_i$ has all elements i.i.d. complex Gaussian random variables.

**Answer:**

The Weyl's theorem ([Is this determinant identity true?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680936/is-this-determinant-identity-true)): If $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ Hermitian  matrices, then $$\tag{Weyl}
\lambda_i(A)+\lambda_n(B)\leq\lambda_i(A+B)\leq\lambda_i(A)+\lambda_1(B), \quad i=1,\ldots,n.$$
Here $\lambda_i(\cdot)$ denotes the $i$th eigenvalue of its argument ordered in the descending order (so that $\lambda_1(\cdot)$ denotes the maximal and $\lambda_n(\cdot)$ the minimal eigenvalue of the argument).

If $B$ is positive semi-definite (and hence $\lambda_n(B)\geq 0$) then we can drop $\lambda_n(B)$ in (Weyl) to get
$$
\lambda_i(A)\leq\lambda_i(A+B), \quad i=1,\ldots,n.
$$ And therefore $\det(A)\leq \det(A+B).$

Now from Weyl's theorem, for $\delta>0$ and let $A=I+a_1A_1+\dots + a_nA_n$ and let $B=\delta A_1$ $$\det(I+a_1A_1+\dots + a_nA_n) \leq\det(I+(a_1+\delta)A_1+\dots + a_nA_n).$$ Since $\det$ of positive definite matrix is always positive we can take the expectation from both sides and we have

$$\mathbb E \det(I+a_1A_1+\dots + a_nA_n) \leq \mathbb E  \det(I+(a_1+\delta)A_1+\dots + a_nA_n).$$ And therefore monotonic in $a_1$. Similar can prove monotonicity for all $a_i$.

Is this answer correct?